# Não instala o xamarin.googleplayservices.base

Tags: android, visual-studio, nuget

Nem rezando, estamos conseguindo instalar o plugin via NuGet:

> xamarin.googleplayservices.base

A mensagem é:

> Não foi possível instalar o pacote 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
>   42.1021.1'. Você está tentando instalar este pacote em um projeto que se destina a 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', mas o pacote não contém
>   nenhuma referência de assembly ou arquivo de conteúdo que seja
>   compatível com essa estrutura. Para obter mais informações, entre em
>   contato com o autor do pacote.

No meu computador eu consegui instalar, mas do meu filho está dando esse erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro diz:

> (...) **Você está tentando instalar este pacote em um projeto que se destina a 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0'**, mas **o pacote não contém nenhuma referência de assembly ou arquivo de conteúdo que seja compatível com essa estrutura**  (...)

Ou seja, você não pode instalar este pacote num projeto **MonoDroid** versão 6.

Você pode confirmar isto abrindo a [página do pacote no Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base/42.1021.1) e verificando a aba dependências.

[image: 2]]